# Why use integration for a fixed timestep game loop? (Gaffer on Games)

Tags: c++, c, game-engine, game-loop

http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/

In the last game loop from Glenn Fiedler's *Fix Your Timestep!* article, he uses an update loop that advances the game logic by a fixed delta time. Since the delta time is fixed, why does he integrate based on delta time? In a fixed timestep based game, can't movement be as simple as:

```
if ( keyboard pressing "W" ) {
    velocity += acceleration
}
position += velocity
```

instead of passing in a delta time varaible:

```
if ( keyboard pressing "W" ) {
    velocity += integrated(acceleration, delta_time)
}
position += velocity * delta_time
```

Because delta time in a "fixed" timestep loop has no purpose, it would be like multiplying everything by 1. In a "variable" timestep based game you would have to use delta time and integrate for motion but in this case it would not matter. Notice how the variable for delta time is set to a constant and never changed, the game logic is already deterministic and it doesn't seem like you need to multiply velocity and acceleration by delta time anywhere in the code. What I took away from the article was "Fix Your Timestep!," as the name implies, so you have deterministic game logic instead of floating point inaccuracies and exploding physics that come with variable timesteps. I was just confused over why delta time was being passed into the update function since it seems to go against the purpose of the article. Both articles in fact make the same argument against delta time.

```
double t = 0.0;
double dt = 0.01;

double currentTime = hires_time_in_seconds();
double accumulator = 0.0;

State previous;
State current;

while ( !quit )
{
    double newTime = time();
    double frameTime = newTime - currentTime;
    if ( frameTime > 0.25 )
        frameTime = 0.25;
    currentTime = newTime;

    accumulator += frameTime;

    while ( accumulator >= dt )
    {
        previousState = currentState;
        integrate( currentState, t, dt ); // integration
        t += dt;
        accumulator -= dt;
    }

    const double alpha = accumulator / dt;

    State state = currentState * alpha + 
    previousState * ( 1.0 - alpha );

    render( state );
}
```

deWiTTERS last game loop does the same thing: fixed timestep, interpolate rendering, render skipping. However it does not mention integration like the other one.

Comment: You should really decide whether you're coding in C or C++.  Very often, the answers in the two languages are often completely different.

Comment: the `time()` function returns a `time_t` (typically a `unsigned long int`,  so this code will not cleanly compile because the output from `time()` is being assigned to a `double`

Comment: @Jonathan The first code block is just pseudo and the latter is in c++ but would be the same as c in this case. Not sure how that matters tho, the question was about fixed time-steps and integrated delta time for a game loop which could be in any language.

Comment: the posted code 'integration' is actually making a 'frame time' to be .25 second and corrects when ever the amount of error is noticeable.  The suggested code depends on when the code gets around to checking the latest keyboard input and IF the keyboard input is a specific letter `W`  The result of the suggested code is the game will move by leaps and spurts and not progress smoothly.

Comment: But delta time is still a constant, game logic always progresses in equal timesteps. But I think you misunderstood the first example let be edit it more.

Comment: Yes; that's why I left it at 'very often' and not as an unconditional statement.  It is, however, a bad idea to get into the habit of dual tagging questions with C and C++ on SO.  You will be down-voted and/or castigated for doing it.

Comment: BTW, this question might have been more suited for gamedev.stackexchange.com

Comment: Does someone know what the 0.25s stands for? Does this avoid the "spiral of death"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that acceleration increases or decreases linearly versus time, you could base velocity change on average acceleration

```
Δv = (a0 + a1)(Δt)/2
```

If the game includes factors like aerodynamic drag, then acceleration is affected by velocity^2, and usually something like Runge Kutta 4 is used to update velocity change and position change for each time step.

---

My impression is that most PC based games use an independent fixed frequency for the physics engine that is ideally independent of frame rate. For these games, even if the display is sluggish the actual game play is the same if the player can deal with the visuals. I've seen older racing games that get this right, where graphics performance doesn't affect the physics, and newer racing games where lowering graphics settings improves the in game car performance, which is a bug.

Link to example Windows code for running a thread at just about any reasonable fixed frequency, with no drift over time.

[16.66ms frames times. How do you get a perfect 60 fps when sleep() only goes by whole milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543478/16-66ms-frames-times-how-do-you-get-a-perfect-60-fps-when-sleep-only-goes-by/27552223#27552223)

In the days of MSDOS, since a PC runs the timer at (105/88) Mhz = 1.19318 Mhz, games use it as a high precision timer counter.

Comment: The timestep for the game logic is not coupled with the rendering if thats what you meant. The nested loop inside the main loop is where the actual game logic is updating, if it takes too long and can't keep up it will skip the rendering and try to catch up by repeating the nested loop. So in that sense it is independent from the display frame rate. It is assumed that the computer is can at least run fast enough for the update loop and then the last priority is to display. However the rendering is interpolated and can run faster then the update loop.

Comment: @YeOldeBitwise - I updated my answer. Some console games, such as the old 8 bit Atari type games may have used a common frequency, but they operate with a fixed performance platform, so it was easy to tune the physics engine to avoid getting behind.

Answer (score 2):

The reason he does it the more complicated way is to decouple the physics simulation frequency from the rendering frequency. This way, you can render at a variable frame rate (120 FPS, 60 FPS, etc) but still update the game logic and physics at a constant rate.

One of the benefits of this is that the game logic will behave the same no matter the FPS (many old games get buggy if you run them on modern computers because their physics depends on the FPS). Another benefit is that you can use the integration logic to interpolate some extra frames between the physics simulation steps, which results in a smoother animation.

Comment: The worst example is the original Wing Command that just ran as fast as the hardware could run it. There was no fixed frequency used for it's physics engine.

Comment: I understand that delta time and integration is for variable timesteps however the entire point of his article was to use fixed timesteps; Yet he has an example function where he passes in delta time to an integration function which makes no sense.

Comment: He uses fixed timesteps for the simulation and variable timesteps for rendering. As opposed to using varied timesteps for both (a common mistake) or fixed timesteps for both (which has choppier animation).

Answer (score 1):

It seems no one has yet considered this: even if you have a fixed timestep and could inline it everywhere in the calculations, using a parameter allows you to do things like slow motion, simply by temporarily decreasing the timestep without executing the physics loop more frequently.

This technique does of course alter the physics behavior during slow motion though, because the physics are suddenly calculated much more precisely. This can be observed in several (modern) games.

Answer (score 0):

A fixed time step, really should only be used in mathematical or scientific applications. Why? Because in a game, if you're running at 30fps then you're delta-time would be around 34ms, meaning that it's taken 34 milliseconds to update the previous frame and be ready to update the next. So a fixed time step, in most applications, is not useful.

When it comes to physics engines, this is almost always entirely dependent on your game but most of the time, a physics engine runs on a separate thread but it will still need to take in the delta time as a parameter, to resolve collisions properly.

Delta time is the time it took to complete the last frame.

I hope this helps.